# write to floppy under ubuntu 15.04

Tags: floppy

I cant write to floppy-disk!
Reading is ok..
But write does not do .. you are not the owner 
Owner is root.

I am new with Linux/ubuntu
So please some detailed info what i should do.
Thanks in advance

Thanks for all lines to try.. but no one did work(OWNER REMAIND  ROOT)
found an solution occasional (just trying some lines from other questions containing the word  floppy)
1. put in floppy disk
2. in a terminal do the following line:
udisks --mount /dev/fd0
(ubuntu had to install udisks-- but did it without great noise)
after that-- i am the owner of the disk!!
write and read works!!
only fromat returns after some scratching on the disk with an time out error.
to change floppy::
1. unmount... udisks --unmount /dev/fd0
2. put in new floppy
3. mount... udisks --mount /dev/fd0

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the terminal output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `ls -lA /dev/fd*`. Then leave me a comment (containing "@ByteCommander") to notify me and I will check your configuration.

Answer (score -3):

Type

```
sudo chmod -R 777 (location of your floppy disk mount point)
```

This makes you the owner.

Comment: Not exactly.  That gives you permissions to write to that directory and it's contents.

Comment: To take ownership, you must execute `sudo chown -R [username]:[username] (mount point)`

Comment: `chmod -R 777` also marks all files in that directory as executable, which is **never** a good idea. At the very least, you should be using something like `chmod -R a+rwX` with the capital `X` instead, but in this case, you should really only change the owner, like Daniel pointed out.